# Secure POP3/SMTP proxy?

Tags: linux, ssl, proxy, smtp, pop3

An ISP doesn't offer secure/encrypted POP3/SMTP connections to its email servers.  (I could forward the mail to another mail service that does, but I'd like to try a proxy)

Is there some simple software that could be run on a linux box to allow secure SSL POP3/SMTP connections to it, and transparently proxy/connect to the ISP email servers?

This is to allow wireless mobile devices more secure access their email without needing the full vpn.

Answer (score 3):

I believe [Perdition](http://horms.net/projects/perdition/) should do the trick, though it may not qualify as “simple”.

This [blog post](http://mikepultz.com/2011/10/secure-email-exim-dovecot-perdition/) shows how to set up the SSL.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly setup [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) to proxy POP/SMTP.  The connection will be encrypted between the client and the host running stunnel, but it will still be un-encrypted between the stunnel host and the ISP.  It certainly cannot be setup transparently though.  Your clients must be configured to use SSL.

- [How to set up a secure POP3 (pop3s) server, using stunnel](http://www.sysdesign.ca/guides/secure_pop3.html)